# What kind of icons does twitter use?

Tags: flutter, dart, twitter, icons

I want to use the twitter icons (home, message, notifications,...) in my flutter app but I don't know its kind. The closest icons in similarity I could find are ionicons but they are not quite the same. If those icons have a name; I'd like to know it. Peace

Comment: did you check flaticon.com? you can find somethings like you want in there.

Comment: I did. But the available icons are similar but not the same